# Using SIGAR API inside a WAR file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-native-interface, war, sigar

I came across Sigar API from Hyperic (http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar) which is a system information and reporting API for Java. It heavily uses JNI to gather data, and standalone version contains .SO and .DLL files in a /lib folder.

It works fine in Standalone mode, but I want to use this library inside a WAR. Is there anyway to do that without specifying the lib path in "-Djava.library.path" when starting the server? I want to be able to bundle it inside the WAR file and deploy it into a running server.

Thanks.

Comment: Nope; that's the way JNI works.  If you don't tell the application how to find the DLLs, it won't be able to figure it out on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the following setup.

I copied all the content (SO / DLL) files to WAR file's lib folder. Then I deployed it to JBoss, and it worked without any custom system property setup.

Is this specific to JBoss? or can I expect this behavior in any J2EE compliant server?

Comment: Could you please clearify: You did place all .so files into WEB-INF/lib of the .war? Thanks

Comment: @alfonx Yes. I copied all .so, .dll, .dylib along with the sigar JAR file into the WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on Sigar for a standalone java program where I had requirement to access host information. I had to use 'java.library.path' variable for loading JNI files. This path is used by Sigar APIs internally for loading libs.
I configured this path using maven. You can refer [here](http://arviarya.wordpress.com/category/java/sigar/), if it helps.

Thanks.